# Where is a singleton instance stored in ninject?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-extensions

The title has it all.  When I do this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
var myClass = kernel.Get<IMyClass>();
```

Where is the instance of MyClass stored?  Is it stored in a static dictionary somewhere globally?  Or is it stored in the kernel instance?

For example if I do this:

```
var kernel1 = new StandardKernel();
var kernel2 = new StandardKernel();
kernel1.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
kernel2.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
var myClass1 = kernel1.Get<IMyClass>();
var myClass2 = kernel2.Get<IMyClass>();
```

Will myClass1 be the same instance as myClass2 or will they be different instances.

*To kind of jump on an inevitable question "Why do you need to do that?":  It doesn't matter.  That is not the point of the question.  I have my reasons and just want to know how this piece works.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Ninject stores them here:

```
  /// <summary>Tracks instances for re-use in certain scopes.</summary>
  public class Cache : NinjectComponent, ICache, INinjectComponent, IDisposable, IPruneable
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains all cached instances.
    /// This is a dictionary of scopes to a multimap for bindings to cache entries.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly IDictionary<object, Multimap<IBindingConfiguration, Cache.CacheEntry>> entries = (IDictionary<object, Multimap<IBindingConfiguration, Cache.CacheEntry>>) new Dictionary<object, Multimap<IBindingConfiguration, Cache.CacheEntry>>((IEqualityComparer<object>) new WeakReferenceEqualityComparer());
...
```

and Cache is scoped to instance of a kernel.

> Will myClass1 be the same instance as myClass2 or will they be
>   different instances.

Different. Cache is not static.

Comment: I ran some tests at the suggestion of juharr (see comment in original question), and those tests indicate different.  I used the same code as above in my question and then did a test to see if "myClass1 == myClass2".  They were in fact the same instance.

Comment: @computrius I ran the same test and obtained two different instances, which is the expected behaviour. Note that the code  posted above comes from Ninject sources https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/5a40fd013ab39b8118ab4c413e5c2ab9414729e9/src/Ninject/Activation/Caching/Cache.cs#L41

Comment: @computrius Probably your test code was flawed. Possible issue: do the types override the Equals method? Different kernel instances will create different singleton instances.

Comment: Ran it again and it seems I was mistaken. Marking this as the answer.

Answer (score -2):

For others that are wondering:  It stores it outside of the kernel.  You will get the same instance with both kernels.

Edit - Test I ran to come to this conclusion:

```
var kernel1 = new StandardKernel();
var kernel2 = new StandardKernel();
kernel1.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
kernel2.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>().InSingletonScope();
var myClass1 = kernel1.Get<IMyClass>();
var myClass2 = kernel2.Get<IMyClass>();
var same = myClass1 == myClass2;
Console.WriteLine(same ? "Same" : "Different");
```

Output: Same

Edit Again:
I must have had a typo because I tested again and got "Different".

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, because my tests indicate it was in fact correct.  I edited the answer with the test I ran.  Unless the discrepancy can be explained to me, it will be the accepted answer in two days..

Comment: I don't think it will be the same. Try `object.ReferenceEquals` method to test for reference equality. Maybe your `MyClass` class overrides the `==` operator?

Comment: It was downvoted, because it's not true. There is no other reason why it should return "Same" apart of what was already mentioned by Yacoub.

Comment: also, you should publish the complete code necessary for the test. The definitions and implementations for the interfaces/class are missing.

Comment: Interesting, it is different with referenceequals.  So then, what is the difference?  I just tested with a base class with no overloading configured for "==".  My understanding is that the only reason for myClass.Equals(...) is that == will compare the reference and not the content.  Is this not the case?  Maybe I just had a typo and overlooked it.

Comment: @computrius As the developer is free to override the equals method, there is no guarantee it actually performs a reference equality check. Hence the need for `ReferenceEquals` - no one can mess with that!

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit Sure, I know that.  But this was a small test class that I wrote myself that did not.  I must have just been mistaken about the result.